# @babel/preset-env version 7 not transforming the null-coalescing operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, babeljs

I'm setting up a new node project with typescript and babel.

I'm using `@babel/preset-env` and `@babel/preset-typescript` and this is my `babel.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          node: "current",
        },
      },
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ],
  plugins: [
  ],
};
```

In my code I use the null-coalescing operator (`x = a ?? b`).

Unfortunately I get an error `Jest encountered an unexpected token` because the null-coalescing syntax is not recognized.

Shouldn't that be included by default by `@babel/preset-env` version 7? I'm targeting node 10.

Using `babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator` fixes the error but I thought that should not be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know so far that babel `preset-env` won't support `stage-x` plugin. This `babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator` seems to be at `stage-4` for now which means you have to keep using this as plugin.

Comment: I noticed that [`babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator` is a dependency of the `preset-env`](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-env/package.json#L26). What's the point of including it if it's not used?

Comment: I'm not sure how they implement but it seems they need to outline all the plugins they have in this preset https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/95fcb3e16c8d08bc4ff2980c4b53fa2506948774/packages/babel-preset-env/src/available-plugins.js